# Simple JavaScript error (is not defined)

Tags: javascript

In the following code i have an error (`Uncaught ReferenceError: devildead is not defined`) why so? I am trying to move an element that is created after another one was deleted in the same place. All works except when i am adding the lines of code for moving that new element.

```
function shoot(e){
        // alert(e.clientX+":"+e.clientY)
        devil=document.querySelectorAll('.devil')

        for(i=0;i<devil.length;i++)
        {
          if (e.clientX>parseInt(devil[i].style.left) )
            if(e.clientY>parseInt(devil[i].style.top) )
              if(e.clientX<parseInt(devil[i].style.left)+75 )
                if(e.clientY<parseInt(devil[i].style.top)+75 )
                 {             
                  topbird=devil[i].style.top
                  leftbird=devil[i].style.left
                  devil[i].parentNode.removeChild(devil[i])
                   die.play();
                   o=document.createElement('img');
                   o.src="img/birddead.png";
                   box.appendChild(o);
                  o.setAttribute("class","devildead");
                  o.style.left=leftbird;
                  o.style.top=topbird;
                      //Starting from here i have an error
                      var delay =1;
                      var top = document.getElementsByClassName("devildead")[i];
                      var currentTop = parseInt(getComputedStyle(devildead[i]).top, 10);               

                      setTimeout(move, delay);
                      function move(){
                        if (currentTop <= 400  ) {
                          currentTop+=2;
                          left.style.top = currentTop + "px";            
                          setTimeout(move, delay); 
                        }
                      }

                 };
        }
```

Comment: You var currentTop = parseInt(getComputedStyle(devildead[i]).top, 10);

Comment: devildead looks to be a string in var top, but a variable in var currentTop. Since devildead is not defined as an object, it errors out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The devildead array is not defined, its tough without the html that accompanies it.

It looks like you need the devildead defined above your array.

```
function shoot(e){
// alert(e.clientX+":"+e.clientY)
    devil=document.querySelectorAll('.devil');

    // Insert new array
    var devildead = document.getElementsByClassName("devildead");
    for(i=0;i<devil.length;i++)
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, it occurs because you try to access an undefined array (`devildead`) on this line:

```
var currentTop = parseInt(getComputedStyle(devildead[i]).top, 10);
```

I suspect that should in fact be (based on the line above it):

```
var currentTop = parseInt(getComputedStyle(devil[i]).top, 10);
```

Comment: It depends what `devildead` should contain?

Comment: it is exactly the same as devil[i], it containes all the images with the class "devildead"

Answer (score 0):

You're referring to `devildead` as a variable in this line:

```
var currentTop = parseInt(getComputedStyle(devildead[i]).top, 10);
```

You haven't defined it anywhere, so you're getting an error when you try to access it.

Comment: "code working" is pretty broad - I'm not sure what your function is trying to do, so I can't definitively tell you what's right. I can tell you why you're getting your error, which will hopefully give you some insight to know what you should be doing instead. You can "delete" the line to remove the error, but that may or may not be logically what you want.

Comment: It will be very usefully for me if you can give me your skype to show you my code, i have another problem easy one for a medium JavaScript coder and i dont know how to ask here :) if you have some time, Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
var currentTop = parseInt(getComputedStyle(devildead[i]).top, 10);
```

You refer to 'devildead' as an object, but it is not an object. There is an element whose className is 'devildead', but you never turned that into a Javascript Object.